# qt, draw center of pixmap at a point, instead of top-left-corner of pixmap at a point

Tags: qt, user-interface, draw, qgraphicsitem, pixmap

Like the title says, I'm drawing a pixmap onto a scene at a specific location. QT draws the pixmap by placing the top left corner of the pixmap at the point I specify. However, I want the center of the pixmap to be placed at this point instead. (Pixmap is crosshairs). Does anyone know how to do this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

`void QPainter::translate ( const QPointF & offset )`

Translates the coordinate system by the given offset; i.e. the given offset is added to points.

```
painter.translate(specific_location);
painter.drawPixmap(-pixmap.rect().center(), pixmap);
```

Answer (score 0):

Translate the specified point by half of the pixmap's width to the left and half of the pixmap's height to the top, then draw pixmap to that point. Just some maths. :)

Comment: But the scene's coordinates aren't measured in pixels.

Comment: I think they are, but it would be much simpler if you provided a fragment of your code responsible for drawing the pixmap - we don't even know are you using C++ or QML.